# Is there a REALLY lightweight gnome extension for old computers, that shows all critical information like IOWait, CPU%, Swap, RAM%?

Tags: 22.04, freeze, gnome-shell-extension, input

Is there a REALLY lightweight gnome extension for old computers, that shows all critical information like IOWait, CPU%, Swap, RAM% ?

The problem is: fancy gnome extensions causing problems with input from keyboard and mouse and causing short freezings making it difficult to use ubuntu 22.04 in an old computer.

I have an old laptop.
I need to know cpu temperature, IOWait, RAM and Swap usage, and a few other critical things but mainly these, to understand if I need to take action like shutdown, reboot, stop some proccess that is causing trouble like overheating or making everything slow down.

I used the gnome extension manager and installed many extensions, I had everything I wanted to know in the systray, with graphics and nice icons, but the problem is that I could barely use the keyboard!!!
Apparently, every time any extension refreshed, it caused trouble with the Window Manager or the CPU. I tested it by holding a key in terminal, and instead of it being quickly repeated smoothly, it would freeze for 2s and suddenly dump about 20+ repeated letters. That problem also happened with ctrl+v, in browsers etc... The keyboard was causing a lot of trouble! The mouse also wouldn't move for a few seconds! I think I had many other problems also related to that.

So, after I disabled ALL the fancy gnome extensions, the problem stopped, but now I am in the dark again. I can't see the infor  I need to save my old PC, any help?

PS.: [Old question with a broader subject]: how to have all critical info on gnome systray without hogging the window manager and cpu in an old computer ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Did the edit improve it? I dont know how I could say less than that, any other tip? The problem is "fancy extensions are causing trouble in my old computer". These extensions should be tested in old computers too before being released because I thought I was having a hardware problem and it was just the fancy extensions. The moment I used a lightweight extension the problem stopped. It is not my fault having to use an old computer, so I don't get the down vote in both the question and the answer! I will post my answer elsewhere too just in case someone needs it.

Answer (score -1):

What I am using is a single gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2826/generic-monitor/

And a script with all I need at https://gist.github.com/Gussak/108eaecb8b0a74bddd252036c2f12657 in case someone needs it.

Obs.: I decided to remove my script (that is working really well and solves the problem to me) from here, because I think that downvote there is just abusive (IMHO it was cast out of hatred and not to tell others that my answer could have some problem). I wont keep my effort under such circumstances, I have self respect.

Comment: I am using a 3s delay tho. I hold a key in terminal and it repeats smoothly for a long time, no mouse lag either! :)